# Android Studio Change Username on Team Foundation Server Plugin

Tags: android, tfs

I am using Android Studio 1.5 with the TFS integration (Team Foundation Server - Version Control Integration ver 0.2.1.200). I have had to change my TFS username and password, but I cannot find where to update this in plugin settings or in Android Studio. Anyone know how to change it?

Comment: Which version of team explorer are you using?  Is this what you are looking for: 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2012/08/29/clearing-the-credentials-for-connecting-to-a-team-foundation-server/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to delete the related credentials which stored in **control panel > Credential Manager> Windows Credentials**

[image]

Then open the android studio and try to connect to TFS server. It will pops up acredential window, just type your new account.

Comment: Thanks, that has removed the credentials.

Comment: Great, if it works, can you mark an answer. So this can help other people.in SO.